# How to scale (transform) div in width and height without scaling border width?

Tags: css

```css
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5);
  }
}

div#scale {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scale 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="scale"></div>
```

How to scale (transform) div in width and height without scaling border width? I'm trying to build [this effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sc-_jtg2soI&t=35s).

Comment: That's not how that microscope (scale transformation) works ... _"I'm trying to build this effect"_ - then animate width & height of an absolutely positioned element, that would be the easiest way to achieve this. (Yes, performance this, repaints that, ... - used moderately, it won't end the world.)

Comment: Please share an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the workaround / alternative you can just animate its `width` and `height`:

```css
body {padding:50px}

#scale {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scale 3s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="scale"></div>
```

To make it grow from the center use negative margins / values for the `top` and `left` properties equal to half of the change in size, so in this case that's `-25px`.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of animating the transform instead of width performance?

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use synced elements. One that `scales` and another one, empty, that changes size while keeping `border-width`. The other element I used is the `::after` of a wrapper.

```css
@keyframes scale-div {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }  
}
@keyframes scale-border {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }  
}

.scale {
  animation: scale-div 5s steps(300, end) infinite ;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.scale,.scale-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.scale-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.scale-wrapper::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  animation: scale-border 5s steps(300, end) infinite;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-wrapper">
  <div class="scale"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But actually I would prefer a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are ton of problems with scaling transforms since it's ratio based. if you scale it, it's going to scale its layout, border even :after, :before elements and all children.
For what you're trying to do it's best if you just use svg. Svg circle element's radius property can be animated. I suggest you run browser support test on it; However, svg support is pretty wide especially with animations.

```css
svg .circle {
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  r: 20px;
  stroke: #dfdfdf;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  fill: none;
  animation: ping 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes ping {
  from {
    r: 10px;
  }
  
  to {
    r: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg><circle r="20px" class="circle"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);  border: 1px solid;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5);  border: 5px solid;
  }
}

div#scale {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scale 5s infinite;
}
```

did you try above code ?

Comment: Don't know who gave you an upvote but he/she clearly didn't try it.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for.